# How to save Data In MongoDB ? Not all the Fields at one single time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I Have created a Schema to store user Details and Some information regarding it's test.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new schema({
  name: { type: String },
  gender: { type: String },
  stream: { type: String },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
  },
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  password: { type: String, required: true },

  // For premium Calculations
  test: {
    type1Count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    type2Count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    type3Count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },

  testCompleted: [
    {
      testId: { type: String },
      testDate: { type: Number },
      testTypeNumber: { type: Number },
      testTypeName: { type: Number },
      testDurationInMinutes: {type: Number},

      listOfQuestionId: [{ type: String }],
      listOfCorrectAnswer: [{ type: Number }],
      listOfAnswerByUser: [{ type: Number }],

      totalNumberOfQuestion: { type: Number },
      numberOfAttemptedQuestion: { type: Number },
      numberOfUnattemptedQuestion: { type: Number },
      numberOfCorrectAnswer: { type: Number },
      numberOfWrongAnswer: { type: Number },
      marksObtained: {type: Number},
      isTestCompleted : {type: Boolean, default: false}
    },
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Now, I am not save all the data at a single time,
first, I will save only it's registration part like Name, Email, password.
code to register user...

```js
const newUser = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password,
      });
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      newUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

      await newUser.save();
```

Now there is a user created in my database.
now I want to save this data ...
// some logics are there, but the data is fine ..

```js
var paper = {
      testId: Object.keys(user.testCompleted).length +1, // I choose Normal serialise Number starting from 1
      testDate: Date.now(),
      testTypeNumber: type,
      testTypeName: testList[type - 1]["testName"],
      testDurationInMinutes: testList[type - 1]["testDurationInMinutes"],
      weightageOfQuestion: list[type - 1],
      totalNumberOfQuestion: list[type - 1]["physics"] + list[type - 1]["chemistry"] + list[type - 1]["biology"],
      listOfQuestionId: arrayOfQuestion,
      listOfCorrectAnswer: arrayOfAnswer,
    };
```

Now I have created a user earlier
and In the later stage, I have to save **paper** data in the testCompleted []  setion, which is a array of objects

and In the later stage i have to store this data .. in the same testCompleted []  setion,

```js
const data = {
    totalNumberOfQuestion: totalNumberOfQuestion,
    numberOfAttemptedQuestion: attempt,
    numberOfUnattemptedQuestion: totalNumberOfQuestion - attempt,
    numberOfCorrectAnswer: attempt - wrong,
    numberOfWrongAnswer: wrong,
    marksObtained: marks,
    isTestCompleted: true
  }
```

Please help me, how to save data partially in mongodb at any points ?

Comment: seperarate the sections into seperate models.   each model should reference the current user. there is a ton of documentation on this, and I have answered this question twice if you want to look through my questions for an example

Answer (score 0):

2 ways for updating array inside documents:

Find the document then use `push()` for adding into array then call `.save()`.

```js
const userToUpdate = await User.find({_id:userId})
userToUpdate.testCompleted.push(data)
userToUpdate.save()
```

Using `findOneAndUpdate()` or `update()`   and `$push`

```js
User.update(
    { _id: userId }, 
    { $push: { testCompleted: data } },
    done
);
```

Reference: [using_nodejs_and_mongoose_to_update_array](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/using-nodejs-and-mongoose-to-update-array-1205#:%7E:text=Working%20with%20arrays%20can%20be,push%2C%20%24pop%2C%20etc.)